# Insert textbox into a string

Tags: string, vb.net, concatenation

I cannot figure out how to get an inventory category into the criteria string without hard coding it.

I tried Concatenation but I can't add a single " to string. Below is an example of the criteria string.  I would like to recreate the string without hard coding the D so I can insert any type.  I'd appreciate any help.  Thank you

```
Dim criteria As String = "Invt.Type  = 'D'"
```

Comment: `Dim criteria As String = $"{Invt.Type} = 'D'"` or `Dim criteria As String = String.Concat(Invt.Type, " = 'D'")` ...?

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that the D in your original code should be variable then the obvious thing to do is to use a variable:

```
Dim criteria As String = "Invt.Type = '" & someVariable & "'"
```

That can be more neatly done using `String.Format`:

```
Dim criteria As String = String.Format("Invt.Type = '{0}'", someVariable)
```

or string interpolation:

```
Dim criteria As String = $"Invt.Type = '{someVariable}'"
```

If you want to get the value of the variable from a `TextBox` then just go ahead and do that:

```
Dim someVariable As String = someTextBox.Text
```

or you can forgo the variable and just go straight from the `TextBox` to the final text:

```
Dim criteria As String = $"Invt.Type = '{someTextBox.Text}'"
```

Comment: The solution you gave me was so simple and worked great.  Thank you very much.  I struggled with this three days and couldn’t find the syntax to help me  and nothing I tried worked.  Thanks again

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the big check/tick mark next to it. That shows everyone who sees your question listed that the issue is resolved without their having to open the question and read your comment.